# substitute for uuencode in UNIX shell scripting (to send an email from UNIX box)

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, uuencode

I have been given a task to automate a script, and I have written a script for this purpose. This script needs to run from both datacentre and AWS. In the end the result needs to be zipped and sent to the intended recipient.

I have used `uuencode` to generate the mail in datacentre, which runs absolutely fine in the datacentre. However, when I run it in AWS, I am getting an error `Syntax error: uuencode, not found`.

Upon searching over the internet, I came to know this is happening because the `uuencode` is not installed in my AWS machine. Which is correct as I verified it.

I am new to coding, any help would really be appreciated. My problem here is that the AWS is a client machine where we are not supposed to install anything new. So, installing `uuencode` is not an option here for me.

Can someone please let me know an alternate command for uuencode.

Here are my linux versions:

Linux AWS version: 3.8.13-55.1.2.el6uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Thu Dec 18 00:15:51 PST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Linux Datacentre version: 2.6.18-194.el5 #1 SMP Mon Mar 29 22:10:29 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

and here is the piece of code I have written:

i

```
f [ -s $WORKINGDIR/Report.zip ]
then

(echo "Hi,

 Please find attached, report for datacentre.

 Please let us know for further clarifications.


Thanks,
JordanForever ";uuencode $WORKINGDIR/Report.zip Report.zip;)| mailx -s "report for datacentre " $MAILLIST
else
(echo "script for datacentre failed.

        Script Details:

                Host: $HOSTNAME
                Path: $WORKINGDIR

";) | mailx -s "Failed: report for datacentre " $FAILURE_MAILLIST
fi
```

I have tried `mutt` and `sendmail` command, but that did not help either.

Can one of you please help me out. I cannot install/uninstall `uuencode`. Any alternate command would help.

Regards

Comment: I'm assuming that you've checked that your implementation of `mailx` on AWS doesn't in fact have the option to attach (and therefore encode) attachments? Look for `-A` (or similar option), but not every `mailx` has this.

Comment: Is `base64` available?  If so, it does Base-64 encoding (and decoding) of data.  It isn't identical to `uuencode` (it won't include filename and permissions information, and you probably want to specify `-b 72` or thereabouts — `-w 72` for the GNU version — to break the lines sensibly, etc).  It is the 'modern' standard encoding, avoiding `uuencode` nasties like trailing blanks on lines of output (which break `uudecode` if removed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need uuencode and you cannot install uuencode, then consider python.  In modern times, python is installed everywhere and uuencode is part of one of its standard modules.

To uuencode `Report.zip` and send the output to stdout, try:

```
python -c 'import sys,uu; uu.encode("Report.zip", sys.stdout)'
```